# Issue initialising the start location of a little mouse over popup form compared to the parent form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, offset, point

Long time lurker, first time poster (I think).

I've got a form with a mouse over hotspot which loads another little form (kind of like a tooltip) but I'm having trouble getting it to initially appear in the right spot. It flashes up in the top left corner of the screen before jumping to where it is supposed to be (offset to the form calling it) according to the code below.

How do I set the initial start coordinates for this little form compared to the bigger form? I've tried quite a few options and the code below seems to work the best except for the microsecond the form is in the wrong spot before correcting itself.

Thanks!

```
       private void lblQuestionMark_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            // show rollover popup and control location

            var loc = new Point
            {
                X = this.Location.X,
                Y = this.Location.Y
            };
            loc.Offset(280, 220);
            rolloverpopup.Location = loc;
            rolloverpopup.Show();
        }
```

I think it needs to go somewhere in the initialize stage. I've got the main form set to screen center, but I'm hoping to be able to set this mini form based on the location of the main form instead of again using screen midpoints and offsets.
thanks

Comment: Is `rolloverpopup` supposed to appear near `lblQuestionMark`? Is that Form hidden at this time? Does *I'm having trouble getting it to initially appear in the right spot* mean that this happens just the first time the Form is shown? In that case, what is its `StartPosition` set to? Something other than `Manual`?

Comment: _except for the microsecond the form is in the wrong spot before correcting itself..._ `Show();` then set the location to fix that. Btw: `rolloverpopup.Location = lblQuestionMark.Parent.PointToScreen(lblQuestionMark.Location);`.

Comment: yes, it was the start position of the form in the properties set to auto. I changed it to manual and it's better now. thanks Jimi and thanks too dr. I'll have a look at that too